# problem with transaction nesting in typeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I have nestjs quiz api which is using graphql and typeORM, teacher can create quiz with questions and questions can have many answers, this information are storing in database and when my createQuiz method call many times createQuestion i decided to implement transaction but i am not sure about my implementation:

createQuiz:

```
async createQuiz(createQuizInput: CreateQuizInput): Promise <Quiz>{
        const {title, questions} = createQuizInput;

        const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();

        await queryRunner.connect();
        await queryRunner.startTransaction();

        try{
            const quiz = this.quizRepository.create({title});
            const savedQuiz = await this.quizRepository.save(quiz);
            savedQuiz.questions = [];

            for(const question of questions){ 
               const savedQuestion = await this.questionService.createQuestion(savedQuiz.id, question);
               savedQuiz.questions.push(savedQuestion);
            }

            await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
            return savedQuiz;
        }
        catch(err){
            await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
            throw new Error(err)
        }
        finally{
            await queryRunner.release();
        }
    }
```

createQuestion used by createQuiz:

```
 async createQuestion(quiz_id: number, createQuestionInput: CreateQuestionInput): Promise<Question>{
    const {question_type, question_content, answers} = createQuestionInput;

    const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();

    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    try{

      const question: DeepPartial<Question> = {
        quiz: {id: quiz_id},
        question_type,
        question_content
      };

      const savedQuestion = await this.questionRepository.save(question);
      savedQuestion.answers = [];

      for (const answer of answers) {
        const savedAnswer = await this.answerService.createAnswer(savedQuestion.id, answer);
        savedQuestion.answers.push(savedAnswer)
      }

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return savedQuestion;
    }
    catch(err){
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      throw new Error(err)
    } 
    finally{
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
```

```
createAnswer:

async createAnswer(question_id: number, createAnswerInput: CreateAnswerInput): Promise <Answer>{
    const { answer_content, is_correct, priority } = createAnswerInput;

    const answer: DeepPartial<Answer> = {
      question: {id: question_id},
      answer_content,
      is_correct,
      priority,
    };

    const savedAnswer = await this.answerRepository.save(answer);

    return savedAnswer;
  }
```

can it work right?

edit: am i correctly returning my quiz and question or it should be after release?